# Combining if condition with button click - in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, click

I am working on a scenario - let's say

```
var clicked=false;
var operate=false;
```

I want something like:

```
if((myButon is clicked) || (operate == true))
{
//escalate operation
}
```

I could use $('myButton').click(function(){ }); to get the click operation but how can I combine this with the OR condition as expressed above?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('myButton').click(function(){ 
  if(operate){
   // do something
  }else{
    // otherwise... let it go or do some other stuff
  }
});
```

Comment: wrong... you applied here and operand not or. 'Do something' must be runnable also without click on button when 'operate' is true

Comment: @Aditzu that condition can either be executed on page load or on some event...that will not execute auto-magically..

Comment: of course that condition can be executed on whatever event he want. In your case event is trigged only if user clicks button and operate is true (which is if((myButon is clicked) && (operate == true))   not if((myButon is clicked) || (operate == true))   )

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){
    if(operate){
        // do smth
    }
});
```

Or:

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){
    if(!operate) return false;
    // do smth
});
```

Comment: Your answers make sense to me and the way I want to write the code is in line with Max and Liam but for whatever reason, it isn't working.  But if I use the ('#myButton').click(function(){}); without any added condition it works.  I am still troubleshooting it... Aditzu I get your point, but I need to combine the conditions somehow.  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var clicked = false;
var operate = false;

$("#myButton").click(function() { clicked = true });

if((clicked) || (operate))
{
//escalate operation
}
```

This should work just as you'd like to, the only thing that could happen is that the script runs before the button has been clicked, so you could check it more often by doing something like this:

```
var escalatedRun = false;

function check() {
    if((clicked) || (operate)) {
        //escalate

        escalatedRun = true;
    }
}

do {
   window.setInterval(check(), 1000);
} while (!escalatedRun)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('myButton').click(function(){
    if(operate){
         // do smth
    }
});
```

or

```
$('myButton').click(function(){ 
  if(operate == true){
   // do something
  }else{
    // otherwise... let it go
  }
});
```

are wrong because they applyed 'and' operand not 'or' as @bdfios wish.

The correct answer is :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('myButton').click(function(){ 

       // do something

    });

if (operate == true){
       // do something
}
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly, are you looking for this?

```
$('myButton').click(function(){
   if((myButon === clicked) || (operate === true))
   {
   //escalate operation
   }
});
```